# Session storage on a separate server

Tags: asp.net, session, load-balancing, session-cookies

I use 3 server through "[Amazon balancer](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/)". On each server installed 2 (asp.net) web application (website, mobile site). "[Balancer-Amazan](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/)"- so constituted that every 3 hours produces load transfer between servers, all session will be crash and creating a new (the users logs off)
Advise the possible solutions to the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but I'm sure it will help me, because I can not get the session state after the load transfer between servers. Session state stored on the servers, I think that I need to create an additional server that will store the session state. My approach is correct?

Comment: *Yes, I agree, but I'm not sure it will help me. Is it possible to store cookies on Balancer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have SQL Server available you can store your session state in that:

> [HOW TO: Configure SQL Server to Store ASP.NET Session State](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604)

You could even implement your own if SQL Server is not available:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178588.aspx
>   [How to: Sample Session-State Store Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178589.aspx)

The only caveats are that you can only store serialisable objects in the store, i.e. you wouldn't, for example, be able to store a `System.Xml.XmlDocument` object without turning it's representation into something than can be serialised, i.e. a string representing the XML.

I wrote up another answer that may be useful/provide further reading:

> [ASP.NET Session size limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6719133/419)