# File Upload Through JQuery AJAX In ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, file-upload, httppostedfilebase

I have a requirement of sending invitations to candidates where a user selects the excel file, transfers it from ajax to controller and validates its size, type etc. Then user clicks on Send Invite button and sends the email invites(having excel file). Please find the below code for reference:

```
<button type="button" id="bulkuploadButton">Bulk Email Upload</button>
<input type="file" id="ExcelFile" name="ExcelFile" style="display:none" onchange="UploadFile();" onselect="UploadFile();" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" />
```

Jquery:

```
function UploadFile() {
  if (ValidateExcelFile()) {
     var excelFile = document.getElementById('ExcelFile');
     formData = new FormData();
     if (excelFile.files.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < excelFile.files.length; i++) {
           formData.append('file-' + i, excelFile.files[i]);
        }
     }
     $.ajax({
       url: url here,
       type: "POST",
       dataType: 'json',
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,
       data: formData,
       success: function (data) {
        // Further Processing
       },
       error: function (err) {
        //Error
       }
     });
   }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult MyController(HttpPostedFileBase excelFile)
{
 if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
 {
   foreach (string file in Request.Files)
   {
     excelFile = Request.Files[file];
   }       
   var result = //Call Model here for validation checks and return error msges
   TempData["ExcelFile"] = excelFile; //Store in TempData for further processing
   return Json(result);
 }     
  return null;
}
```

The validations are done successfully, now its time to send invite to candidates as:

```
<button onclick="SendInvite">Send Invitations</button>
```

Jquery:

```
function SendInvite() {
  //Check validations for other inputs on the page

  //Get the excel file same as above
  var excelFile = document.getElementById('ExcelFile');
  formData = new FormData();
  if (excelFile.files.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < excelFile.files.length; i++) {
      formData.append('file-' + i, excelFile.files[i]);
    }
  }
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url here,
    data: JSON.stringify({
           myModel: myModel,
           excelFile: formData
          }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
    },
    error: function (data) {
    }
   });
}
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult MyController2(MyModel myModel, HttpPostedFileBase excelFile)
{
 //I tried the same method to get the file but it didn't help me
 if (Request.Files.Count > 0)  //Here Request.Files.Count = 0, it should be = 1 instead
 {
  foreach (string file in Request.Files) 
  {
    excelFile = Request.Files[file];
  }
 }

 //I then tied to use TempData but it does not have the excel data

 excelFile = TempData["ExcelFile"] as HttpPostedFileBase;

 //Further processing
```

I am getting this error while fetching data from TempData. ContentLength is 0 and also the data attribute is null
[image: Error]

The data in TempData should be something like this (where ContentLength !=0
and data attribute has some value):

[image: TempData]

Can anyone help me get the excel data in controller MyController2.

Comment: Do you want to send an invite via mail? Can you please be more specific about what error you are exactly getting?

Comment: @TBA, I have already specified that I want to send the email invites to candidates. I have now added images for the error I am getting

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22706663/how-to-send-file-from-action-to-other-action-using-session-or-tempdata-in-mvc?noredirect=1&lq=1  hope this will help you.

Comment: @Neeraj,
getting `null` value in `excelFile` of `MyController`, hence stuck here.

Comment: there is maybe some mistake in sending file using ajax just directly send file in append formdata check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax

Comment: Try this [How to Pass Image File and Form Data From Ajax to MVC Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58352020/how-to-pass-image-file-and-form-data-from-ajax-to-mvc-controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the function SendInvite() as:

```
function SendInvite() {
  //Check validations for other inputs on the page

  //Get the excel file same as above
  var excelFile = document.getElementById('ExcelFile');
  formData = new FormData();

  formData.append("data", JSON.stringify(myModel));

  for (var i = 0; i < excelFile.files.length; i++) {
     var file = ExcelFile.files[i];
     formData.append("excelFile", file);
  }
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url here,
    data: formData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
    },
    error: function (data) {
    }
   });
}
```

and in controller

```
public JsonResult MyController2(string data, HttpPostedFileBase[] excelFile)
{
 MyModel myModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(data);
 if (Request.Files.Count > 0)  
 {
  //Do data processing here
 }    

 //Further processing
```

Check this link [How to Pass Image File and Form Data From Ajax to MVC Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58352020/how-to-pass-image-file-and-form-data-from-ajax-to-mvc-controller)